# I don't understand the result of broadcast example of spark

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast

I ran the broadcast example of spark, the code was:

```
object BroadcastTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val bcName = if (args.length > 2) args(2) else "Http"
    val blockSize = if (args.length > 3) args(3) else "4096"

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Broadcast Test")
      .set("spark.broadcast.factory", s"org.apache.spark.broadcast.${bcName}BroadcastFactory")
      .set("spark.broadcast.blockSize", blockSize)
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
    val num = if (args.length > 1) args(1).toInt else 1000000

    val arr1 = (0 until num).toArray

    for (i <- 0 until 3) {
      println("Iteration " + i)
      println("===========")
      val startTime = System.nanoTime
      val barr1 = sc.broadcast(arr1)
      val observedSizes = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, slices).map(_ => barr1.value.size)
      // Collect the small RDD so we can print the observed sizes locally.
      observedSizes.collect().foreach(i => println(i))
      println("Iteration %d took %.0f milliseconds".format(i, (System.nanoTime - startTime) / 1E6))
    }

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

After running, the result was showed:

```
Iteration 0
===========
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
Iteration 0 took 805 milliseconds
Iteration 1
===========
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
Iteration 1 took 34 milliseconds
Iteration 2
===========
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
Iteration 2 took 32 milliseconds
```

I don't understand why the time spending at Iteration 1 was longer than Iteration 2 and Iteration3. I figured out the time of the three Iterations must be almost same. I hope you can explain this reason, thank you.

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT It has nothing to do with broadcasting.

Comment: `val barr1 = sc.broadcast(arr1)`in the block of For loop. So, within the each iteration,  the barr1 variable was a new instance. But, from the result above, I didn't figure out this effect. Why?

Comment: @zero323,Sorry, I don't understand meaning what you express. the code `val observedSizes = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, slices).map(_ => barr1.value.size)` done the function of the broadcasting

Comment: The difference you see here has nothing to do with broadcasting process. You can easily confirm that by removing removing broadcasting completely. Moreover if check UI and compare task execution times you should see much smaller differences. So what happens? There is a lot of stuff that has to be in place for context to work and many objects are lazily initialized hence initial job can have higher latency than the subsequent ones.